# Join three tables and count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is really complicated, then I will say an example in order to make it easier.

Imagine that we have 4 tables: garages, cars, securities, places.

`garages` is where you can find the `cars`, `securities` is the security that is keeping that car safe inside of a garage, and `places` is where you can find garages similar to that one. Then we have a table like that.

garages table:

```
-----------------------------------
|garage_id|garage_name|garage_size|
-----------------------------------
|        1|   Garage 1|        200|
-----------------------------------
|        2|   Garage 2|        400|
-----------------------------------
```

cars table:

```
---------------------------
|car_id|car_name|garage_id|
---------------------------
|     1|   Car 1|        1|
---------------------------
|     2|   Car 2|        1|
---------------------------
|     3|   Car 3|        2|
---------------------------
```

securities table:

```
----------------------------------
|security_id|security_name|car_id|
----------------------------------
|          1|  Security 1|      1|
----------------------------------
|          2|  Security 2|      1|
----------------------------------
|          3|  Security 3|      2|
----------------------------------
|          4|  Security 4|      3|
----------------------------------
```

places table:

```
-------------------------------
|place_id|place_name|garage_id|
-------------------------------
|       1|   place 1|        1|
-------------------------------
|       2|   place 2|        1|
-------------------------------
|       3|   place 3|        1|
-------------------------------
|       4|   place 4|        2|
-------------------------------
|       5|   place 5|        2|
-------------------------------
```

What I want is to list the garages and join the three tables that is cars, securities and places like this:

> Garage 1 has 2 cars with 3 securities and has 3 more garages similar
>
> Garage 2 has 1 cars with 1 securities and has 2 more garages similar

Now you might ask, why `Garage 1` has 3 securities? Because the `Garage 1` has `Car 1` and `Car 2` and `Car 1` has two securities `Security 1` and `Security 2` and `Car 2` has 1 that is `Security 3`.

The problem here is: How to join the tables and count in one single query and return the result just like you can see above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply join all tables, group by garage and count distinct matches:

```
select 
  g.garage_name, 
  count(distinct c.car_id) as count_cars,
  count(distinct s.security_id) as count_securities,
  count(distinct p.place_id) as count_places
from garages g
left join cars c on c.garage_id = g.garage_id
left join securities s on s.car_id = c.car_id
left join places p on p.garage_id = g.garage_id
group by g.garage_name
order by g.garage_name;
```

As to the desired output strings, concatenate your results:

```
g.garage_name || ' has ' || count(distinct c.car_id) || ' cars with ' || ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 gb.garage_name,
 (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars_table ct WHERE ct.garage_id = db.garage_id
 ) as car_count,
 (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM security_table st JOIN cars_table ct ON ct.car_id = st.car_id WHERE ct.garage_id = db.garage_id
 ) as security_count,
FROM
garages_table gb
ORDER BY gb.garage_id
```

This is untested, but it's an idea.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the job:

```
SELECT g.garage_id, g.garage_name, COUNT(c.car_id) AS nb_cars,
    COUNT(s.security_id) AS nb_securities, COUNT(p.place_id) AS nb_places
FROM garages g
    LEFT JOIN cars c ON g.garage_id = c.garage_id
    LEFT JOIN securities c.car_id = s.car_id
    LEFT JOIN places.p ON g.garage_id = p.garage_id
GROUP BY g.garage_id
```

You will get the list of all garages, including those that do not have cars or places around. If you want to filter out the garages without cars then use `INNER JOIN cars ...`. To filter out the garages without places, use `INNER JOIN places ...`.